# Pasar los datos de una lista a una hoja de cálculo, mediante dos celdas de la hoja - Python

Tags: python, excel

Estoy empezando a aprender a comunicar script *Python* con hojas de cálculo. Con el script de *Python* he conseguido importar de internet, una lista de datos (fecha, valor), y también puedo tener los mismos datos en un diccionario. Ahora necesito copiar esos datos, en dos columnas de una hoja de cálculo, a partir de dos celdas determinadas. Mediante `openpyxls` he visto cómo puedo hacerlo celda a celda. Como la lista tiene más de 1000 registros, esto es implanteable. ¿Cómo puedo iterar para hacerlo de forma automática dentro del script de Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supongo que lo que quieres hacer es meter en una columna las fechas y en otra los valores de cada fecha. Si tienes los datos en un diccionario podrias hacerlo asi:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from datetime import datetime

#Diccionario de ejemplo
datos = {'01/01/2016':100, '02/01/2016':102, '03/01/2016':103, '04/01/2016':104,
         '05/01/2016':105, '06/01/2016':106, '07/01/2016':107, '08/01/2016':108,
         '09/01/2016':109, '10/01/2016':110, '11/01/2016':111, '12/01/2016':112}


wb = Workbook()
ruta = 'salida.xlsx'

hoja = wb.active
hoja.title = "Fecha-Valor"

fila = 1 #Fila donde empezamos
col_fecha = 1 #Columna donde guardamos las fechas
col_dato = 2 #Columna donde guardamos el dato asociados a cada fecha

for fecha, dato in datos.items():
    hoja.cell(column=col_fecha, row=fila, value=datetime.strptime(fecha, '%d/%m/%Y').date())
    hoja.cell(column=col_dato, row=fila, value=dato)
fila+=1

wb.save(filename = ruta)
```

El `xlsx` que nos crea es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si te fijas cada fecha tiene su valor asociado en la columna de al lado pero las filas no tienen el mismo orden que tenian los datos originalmente. Es importante que tengas en cuenta que un diccionario es un **conjunto no ordenado** de parejas clave-valor, por lo que al usar un diccionario las filas no tendran el mismo orden que tenian originalmente.

Si quieres mantener el orden, es mejor que uses listas. Si tienes tus datos en dos listas distintas puedes crearlo asi:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from datetime import datetime

fechas = ['01/01/2016', '02/01/2016', '03/01/2016', '04/01/2016',
          '05/01/2016', '06/01/2016', '07/01/2016', '08/01/2016',
          '09/01/2016', '10/01/2016', '11/01/2016', '12/01/2016']

datos = [100, 102, 103, 104,
         105, 106, 107, 108,
         109, 110, 111, 112]


wb = Workbook()
ruta = 'salida.xlsx'

hoja = wb.active
hoja.title = "Fecha-Valor"

fila = 1 #Fila donde empezamos
col_fecha = 1 #Columna donde guardamos las fechas
col_dato = 2 #Columna donde guardamos el dato asociados a cada fecha

for fecha, dato in zip(fechas, datos):
    hoja.cell(column=col_fecha, row=fila, value=datetime.strptime(fecha, '%d/%m/%Y').date())
    hoja.cell(column=col_dato, row=fila, value=dato)
    fila+=1

wb.save(filename = ruta)
```

Si los datos estan en una lista de tuplas como esto:

```
datos = [('01/01/2016', 100), ('02/01/2016', 102), ('03/01/2016', 103), ('04/01/2016', 104),
         ('05/01/2016', 105), ('06/01/2016', 106), ('07/01/2016', 107), ('08/01/2016', 108),
         ('09/01/2016', 109), ('10/01/2016', 110), ('11/01/2016', 111), ('12/01/2016', 112)]
```

Simplemente cambia la linea del `for` por:

```
for fecha, dato in datos:
```

Ahora el resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver así si se mantiene el orden original de los datos.

Las fechas las paso a un tipo apropiado con `datetim` para que el formato de las celdas sea el de fecha. Si no se hace esto el formato será un string (cadena). Si tus fechas tiene un formato distinto puede que tengas que adaptar esto.

Al no saber el formato de tus datos ni como los tienes almacenados (dos listas, una lista con tuplas de parejas, diccionario con la fecha como clave, etc) no puedo adaptarme a tu caso. De todas formas sea como sea la idea es esta, si tienes problemas edita tu pregunta añadiendo esa información.

*El código ha sido probado en `Python 3.5.2` con `openpyxls 2.4.0`*

Comment: Me esta ayudando a avanzar, unn montón. Además estoy consultando estos interesantes links, que les pueden servir a otras personas, con el mismo fin.

Comment: Gracias FJSevilla. Me quedaros los enlaces.  "http://ironsistem.com/tutoriales/python/modificar-documentos-de-excel-con-python/" y "http://www.pythonexcel.com/openpyxl.php"

Comment: @FJSevilla en el primer código, me parece que el contador quedó fuera del for por un error de indentación

Comment: @efueyo si esto responde a tu pregunta, por favor considera **[aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la respuesta (no se te descuenta nada por eso, todo lo contrario, ambos ganan reputación).

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, he rodeado demasiado e ineficientemente. El Data Frame se puede crear directamente así:

## Import the excel un archivo y llamarlo xls_file

```
wb = pd.ExcelFile('cotizaciones.xlsx')
```

## Mostrar los nombres de las hojas del libro

```
wb.sheet_names
df =wb.parse('Sheet')
print (df)
```