# Openpyxl - SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Tags: python, excel

Con el siguiente script intento conseguir los datos de un rango de celdas:

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('testfile.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1')
# Imprimir un rango 
multiple_cells = sheet['A1':'C20']
for row in multiple_cells:
    for cell in row:
        print cell.value
```

Al ejecutarlo me da el error:

```
File "E:/Python/Openpyxl/Practicas_openpyxl.py", line 43
    for cell in row:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

No consigo darme cuenta de donde está el fallo.

Por otro lado, ¿Es posible darle un nombre de variable al rango importado y convertirlo en un DataFrame?. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?.

Comment: ¿Con qué codificación estas guardando tu script?

Comment: Es posible que un caracter no visible esté presente en tu archivo. Puedes intentar borrar la linea donde sale el error completamente y volverla a escribir o copiar y pegar esa linea en un editor hex y verás si existe algún caracter adicional.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Pasar los datos de una lista a una hoja de cálculo, mediante dos celdas de la hoja - Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36060/pasar-los-datos-de-una-lista-a-una-hoja-de-c%c3%a1lculo-mediante-dos-celdas-de-la-ho)

Answer (score 0):

Funciono con Anaconda3 y Spyder. Los archivos los scripts los guardo como ficheros python.
Respecto a la primera pregunta formulada, se solucionó así:

> ## seleccionar un rango
>
> seleccion = sheet['A1':'B23']
>   for filas in seleccion:
>       for columnas in filas:
>           print (columnas.value)

En cuanto a la segunda pregunta, existe una contestación anterior, a una pregunta también mía, que en principio me sirve. Se encuentra en el link:

[Pasar los datos de una lista a una hoja de cálculo, mediante dos celdas de la hoja - Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36060/pasar-los-datos-de-una-lista-a-una-hoja-de-c%C3%A1lculo-mediante-dos-celdas-de-la-ho)

Gracias